# command line parser in c ++

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line, console

I have the next code :

```
#include "CmdLine.h"

void main(int argc, TCHAR **argv)
{

  CCmdLine cmdLine;



  // parse argc,argv 
  if (cmdLine.SplitLine(argc, argv) < 1)
  {
     // no switches were given on the command line, abort
     ASSERT(0);
     exit(-1);
  }

  // test for the 'help' case
  if (cmdLine.HasSwitch("-h"))
  {
     show_help();
     exit(0);
  }

  // get the required arguments
  StringType p1_1, p1_2, p2_1;
  try
  {  
     // if any of these fail, we'll end up in the catch() block
     p1_1 = cmdLine.GetArgument("-p1", 0);
     p1_2 = cmdLine.GetArgument("-p1", 1);
     p2_1 = cmdLine.GetArgument("-p2", 0);

  }
  catch (...)
  {
     // one of the required arguments was missing, abort
     ASSERT(0);
     exit(-1);
  }

  // get the optional parameters

  // convert to an int, default to '100'
  int iOpt1Val =    atoi(cmdLine.GetSafeArgument("-opt1", 0, 100));

  // since opt2 has no arguments, just test for the presence of
  // the '-opt2' switch
  bool bOptVal2 =   cmdLine.HasSwitch("-opt2");

  .... and so on....
```

}

I have the CCmdLine class implemented and this main is an exemple of how to use it .
I am having difficulties understanding how i get input values . I have tried to read them with scanf from the console but the argc won't increment and results faulty reading.

I am a beginner in c++ and i would like to know who to make this code work .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Argc` and `argv` *only* contain the arguments that were passed when the program started. So if you execute it with `myapp.exe option1 option2 option3`, than in your `argv` you will have:

- myapp.exe `//<--argv[0]`
- option1 `//<--argv[1]`
- option2 `//<--argv[2]`
- option3 `//<--argv[3]`

In a nutshell, when a program starts, the arguments to main are initialized to meet the following conditions:

- `argc` is greater than zero.
- `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.
- `argv[0]` through to `argv[argc-1]` are pointers to strings representing the actual arguments.
- `argv[0]` will be a string containing the program's name or a null string if that is not available. Remaining elements of `argv` represent the arguments supplied to the program.

You can find some more information for example [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html).

All attempts to read input later (either with `cin`, `scanf` or whatever else) will not save the inputed values to `argv`, you will need to handle the input yourself.

Comment: hey, thanks .This was usefull ,i understand how argc and argv work ,but what do you mean by handle the input myself ? could you give me an exemple ? .Thanks.

Comment: @Ion, I mean that you need to save stuff that you are getting from the console yourself: `void main(void){char string[128]; cin.getline(string, sizeof(string));/*getting the input from console, and putting it into th string variable*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

pass the input values from commandline while run the programs
e.g

```
program_name.exe arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string arg1(argv[0]);
    std::string arg2(argv[1]);
}
```